# Elementary proof that $\sin$ is the unique function for which $y'' = -y$ with $y(0) = 0$ and $y'(0)=1$

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry, alternative-proof

Defining $\sin$ by means of the exponential function or by power series, it is straightforward to show that $\sin$ satisfies:
$$y''=-y, \ \ \ \ y(0)=0, \ \ \ \ y'(0)=1.$$
There is an [elementary proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4194882/362026) that there is a unique solution to the above **on the reals**. I wonder if the argument can be extended to, or if there is another elementary proof that shows there is a unique solution in the complex plane.

Comment: Is [permanence of analytic relations](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrincipleofPermanence.html) "elementary"...?

Comment: Which part of that proof are you afraid doesn't apply to $\Bbb C$?

Comment: @Arthur that proof doesn’t apply word for word. For instance, there it is used that if a sum of squares vanishes then each term vanishes. Of course this is modifiable.

Comment: actually scratch that, the above Energy-proof doesn’t seem easily modifiable. I’d resort to uniqueness of analytic continuation. Or just directly use the equation to recursively figure out $y^{(n)}(0)$ for all $n\geq 0$, and then check the resulting power series converges, and so we’re done.

Comment: what does elementary mean in this context - since you extend an ODE to $\mathbb C$ you automatically have to assume the general theory of differentiability of complex functions for the question to make sense, so in particular power series etc; in other words when you talk about complex analysis, power series are as elementary as it gets which is definitely not the case for real analysis, where real analyticity is quite a subtle phenomenon

Comment: @peek-a-boo I addressed my comment specifically to the OP, in the hopes that they would have a closer look and give us some insight into their thoughts on the problem.

Comment: @Arthur precisely the part that peek-a-boo mentioned.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang yes (:

Comment: @peek-a-boo could you elaborate on how to "recursively figure out $y^{(n)}(0)$ for all $n\ge 0$, and then check the resulting power series converges"?

Comment: Look at your ODE. If you know $y(0)$, then you automatically know $y’’(0)$, which then automatically tells you $y^{(4)}(0)$, and so on. Since you know both $y(0),y’(0)$, you can keep jumping in steps of two to figure out all the derivatives at the origin.